# Programmatically upgrade Nuget package on DLL load

Tags: c#, nuget

My Scenario:
I am writing one C# class library and I need to use one of the nuget package from a private feed. There may be a chance that new version of the dependent nuget package would have been released.
My requirement here is "I want to check the nuget feed for latest version and if available upgrade the nuget package with the latest version". Like deleting the existing version and install new version or any other way.

I was trying with NuGet.Client (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-client-sdk), But not found exact solution.

Could you please suggest me a solution for my scenario.

Comment: there isn't a way to do that really cleanly at run time. it also opens your application/service to risks

Comment: This just sounds like an amazing new way of introducing incredibly hard to find bugs into your program...

Comment: Yeah, it's a bad idea. You want a CI\CD pipeline that can update and deploy a new version when a NuGet package is updated. You then run this daily. You would need rock solid testing in place for this to work without automagically breaking itself as RB pointed out.

Comment: Thank You All for your response. I understand the issue you are mentioning. But I am planning to write this class library as a mediator, I mean no additional logic will be there. So chances for bugs will be very less, only problem is I need to return the data always as latest model, I dont want to push the upgrade of the model logic to clients.

Comment: Actual issue is, I have an API and the Data Contracts, We will be updating Data Contracts regularly and some of our API clients dont want to upgrade the data contracts. So I am planning to write this class library which upgrade the Data Contracts nuget package always and return the latest data. We dont have API versioning in place, So thought of this option. Hope you got my issue and happy to see your suggestions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.